# What is the meaning of star in <VirtualHost *:80> in apache?

Tags: apache2

I want to know the use of this `*` and how to configure it?

Comment: It might be better to ask on serverfault - there is a post on there: https://serverfault.com/questions/567320/difference-between-default-and-in-virtualhost-context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

* means a wildcard when you use wildcard you do bifurcation on ServerName

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/app1
  ServerName app1.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example
  ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache will route example.com to /var/www/example where as app1.example.com would be routed to /var/www/app1

Answer (score 0):

`VirtualHost` directive allows you to configure and use multiple sites located on the same IP address. In this case, with `*:80` you are creating a virtual host for every request coming on the port 80. It becomes more interesting when you start specializing and start to insert something other than `*` in the virtual host. An example can be, that according to the IP address with which a port is hit, you can open a different version of a web site, perhaps with different resources like: language translations, styles etc.